# Using $wgScriptPath within extension

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'd like to use the `$wgScriptPath` variable inside a mediawiki extension I'm building.  Any time I access the variable I get the error "Undefined variable: wgScriptPath".
Does anyone know the correct way to access these types of variables inside mediawiki extensions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When are you referencing it? An example would be very helpful. Give us code! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you declare it as a global?

```
function foo() {
    echo $wgScriptPath; // this will echo the local variable in the 
                        // function's scope, which of course does not exist
}

function foo() {
    global $wgScripPath;
    echo $wgScriptPath; // this will echo the global variable
}
```